# What image resoluiton for sprites in 2D mobile game?

Tags: unity, sprites, resolution

I am an experienced iOS developer, however I have never worked on games before. We are planning to make a mobile game using Unity 3D.

Our graphics designer needs to know what resolution should he design our sprites in? I know that we will have to use different sizes for the different screen resolutions, but my question is:

**What is the largest resolution we will need the sprites to be in, considering future-proofness?**

OR

**Shall we go with vector graphics?**

We are targeting tablets as well!

Comment: Depends. What size does your game need? This is so specific to your situation that it'll be hard to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

If cost and time-wise `svg` is the same to you (and your graphic designer) as a raster sprite, then you should go with `svg`.

`Svg` is not necessarily easy to use in Unity natively nor is it supported out of the box. If you want to do this, [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/611635/anyway-to-import-vectors-ai-svg-eps.html) recommends these:

- [SVG Assets - $125](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19822)
- [SVG Importer - $50](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38258)
- [Simply SVG - $30](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/46496)
- [and there's more... just search on the Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/46496)

But, if it's in `svg` you can always rescale them and export them to whatever size you need as raster later when you do decide on a resolution.

If you're worried about the added implications of making an `svg` (cost, time, etc) and want to just go with raster you need to consider the resolution and dpi of your target devices. If you don't have target devices yet, you should probably do a trade study. This might entail:

1. Taking the most popular phones on the market
2. Noting their resolutions
3. Comparing your assets scale in the game with how much of the resolution they will take up
4. Multiply by two to ensure that you have crisp assets when rendered in the game.

This is kind of a cost, time and quality trade-off and is project specific which is something you need to decide on. There is no one right answer but many rule of thumbs that will help you decide.